# IIS and Apache hosting together

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, nat, port-forwarding

I know similar questions have been asked already, but mines a little more unique.

I work for an internet/networking company. We build and host websites, as well as provide internet and network setups for businesses.

I want to know if it's possible to run IIS and Apache together on the same system to host separate sites on each with the way our clients network is setup.

For this client they have their own server at our location. Which is tunneled to their local network at their building. traffic is nat'd to the server we host since its setup as part of the clients network and not our network.

So my questions is, Since their traffic is already being forwarded to the server from our network, can the request be forwarded again to either ISS listening port or Apache listening port based on the url/domain name without having to include the port in the url?

Hope my question makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Apache's mod_rewrite or the IIS equivalent. I sort of question why they're attempting to run both IIS and Apache on the same machine when they will (evidently) serve different VirtualHosts (to use Apache terminology), but you can make this work. Well, they can, since I assume they are in control of the software configuration on this machine.

Comment: Their server is windows server 2008 r2 and hosts several of their sites on iis, We are replacing one of their old e-commerce sites with an new updated version, but need SEO urls, so we need to put the new site on apache, cause reconfiguring iis could possibly break their other sites. We have complete control of their server

Comment: Ok, then again, it is possible, but IMHO, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that. Apache/PHP on windows is VERY slow and has some limitations like memory with it's 32-bit operation, thread safe worker, php nts etc.
It's better to run one in virtualized environment.

In had cases with double performance improvement (minimum) and with over 100x of performance improvement.

So, you can run Windows on Centos (KVM is a good thing), or Centos or windows (ex. Virtualbox) - both will have better results and will be much easier to set up and maintain.